# Android: After enabling the Proguard API call is not working

Tags: android, apache, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-proguard

I just enable the proguard in my application. Am using `org.apache.http` method for API calling.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

When I first enable the Proguard am getting the warning when I try to generate release APK

```
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory extends or implements program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning:library class android.webkit.WebViewClient depends on program class android.net.http.SslError
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
```

So I add some rules in Proguard

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**
```

After the release APK is successfully generated, But the API is not calling.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Comment: Logs would be helpful

Comment: Log or it didn't happen

Comment: Proguard is working in release apk , so how can i get Log. I check the server, it shows there is no calling to server @Much Overflow

Comment: how i get logs. its release apk @Ragesh Ramesh

Comment: am not getting any exception @Hammad Tariq Sahi

Comment: @BinilS try build a debug version with proguard enabled. And check the log when you make an HTTP call in LogCat

Answer (score 3):

ProGuard obfuscation will convert the Model classes Names so if you are passing these class name in the post method using Gson the API will not work so keep all the Model classes like below

```
-keep class com.android.appname.** { *; }
(The package name of the you app)
-dontwarn com.android.appname.**
```

Comment: -dontwarn com.android.appname.** without class